# How do I output a match after comparing two tables?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I want to compare two tables.
But I don't know what to do because I'm not good enough.
I want to know how to write query

no.1_table

```
id  chart_num       chart_name            visit            card_amount_received
1        4            user1             2020-04-05               1000                        
2        5            user2             2020-05-05               1000           
3        5            user2             2020-05-05               1000                        
4        5            user2             2020-06-05               1000              
5        6            user3             2020-07-05               1000        
6        6            user3             2020-08-05               1000                 
7        7            user4             2020-09-05               1000                    
8        7            user4             2020-09-05               1000
```

no.2_table

```
id           card_date             advenced_amount
1        2020-04-05 17:28:00            1000        
2        2020-05-05 12:12:12            2000   
10       2020-11-05 12:12:12            5000
```

**want result**
[image]

**The conditions and order are as follows.**

1. no.1_table, sum a column with the same value of each chart_num and visit.
2. Compare the visit and card_count_received of the result value of number 1 with the card_date and the advenced_amount values of no.2_table.
3. If the value of chart_num and visit of no.1_table is the same as the card_date of no.2_table and the added_count value of no.2_table, ok otherwise output error with null processing.

How do I create a query statement?

Database skills are insufficient. Please give me a reply.

Comment: 'associated_count of' - what's this?

Comment: I modify complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. no.1_table, sum a column with the same value of each chart_num and visit.

For this you want to [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) the chart_num and visit. Any rows with the same chart_num and visit will appear as a single row in the result. Then you can [`sum`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) the amount received, this will add up all the values for a group.

```
select
  chart_num,
  visit,
  sum(card_amount_received) as card_amount_received
from table1
group by chart_num, visit
```

`chart_name` is a problem. You can't display it as it is not part of the `group by`. It's a string so it doesn't make sense to aggregate it with functions like `sum` or `count`. Though in the data chart_num has the same chart_name, that is not guaranteed.

One solution is to use [`group_concat`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) to concatenate each name in a group together. There should only be one name per group.

```
select
  chart_num,
  visit,
  group_concat(chart_name) as chart_name,
  sum(card_amount_received) as card_amount_received
from table1
group by chart_num, visit
```

However, the proper solution is fix the schema. chart_name is duplicated, and that's to be avoided. Instead, move the chart columns into their own table. Then to get the chart name, join on the chart_num.

```
create table charts (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null
);

insert into charts (id, name) values
  (4, 'user1'), (5, 'user2'), (6, 'user3'), (7, 'user4');

alter table table1 drop column chart_name;

select
  charts.id as chart_num,
  visit,
  charts.name as chart_name,
  sum(card_amount_received) as card_amount_received
from table1
join charts on charts.id = chart_num
group by chart_num, visit
```

> 2. Compare the visit and card_count_received of the result value of number 1 with the card_date and the advanced_amount values of no.2_table.

We need a left join with the second table matching the card_date with the visit. [A left join means all the rows in the "left" table (ie. the `from` table) will always appear even if there is no match in the join table](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

visit is a date. card_date is not a date but a timestamp. To match them we'll need to convert `card_date` to a date.

```
select
  charts.id as chart_num,
  visit,
  charts.name as chart_name,
  sum(card_amount_received) as card_amount_received,
  table2.card_date,
  table2.advanced_amount as amount
from table1
join charts on charts.id = chart_num
left join table2 on date(table2.chart_date) = visit
group by chart_num, visit
```

> If the value of chart_num and visit of no.1_table is the same as the card_date of no.2_table and the added_count value of no.2_table, ok otherwise output error with null processing.

We need to compare advanced_amount with sum(card_amount_received). If they're equal: ok. If not: error. In standard SQL we'd use a [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp), but MariaDB has a non-standard [`if`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if-function/) that is much more compact.

```
select
  charts.id as chart_num,
  visit,
  charts.name as chart_name,
  sum(card_amount_received) as card_amount_received,
  table2.card_date,
  table2.advanced_amount as amount,
  if(table2.advanced_amount = sum(card_amount_received), 'ok', 'error') as result
from table1
join charts on charts.id = chart_num
left join table2 on date(table2.chart_date) = visit
group by chart_num, visit
```

Comment: Sorry for checking late.

Thank you. I'll try as you say.

Comment: can you cheat me?