# How do I join two tables and compare them? (I've asked several times, but I couldn't find the answer.)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I want to compare table 1 and table 2 only once.
I want to print the same amount as the wrong amount or the data error on each side.

1.table name : hospital_payment_data

```
id    chart_num        chart_name          visit            card_amount_received
1        9740            t1             2019-01-02               1000                        
2        23143           t2             2019-01-02               3000          
3        14220           t3             2019-01-02               3000                        
4        2000            t4             2019-01-02               4000      
5        3000            t5             2019-01-02               5000      
6        3000            t5             2019-01-02               5000      
7        4000            t6             2019-01-02               6000      
8        5000            t7             2019-01-02               6000
```

2.table name : credit_card

```
id           card_date             advenced_amount
1           2019-01-02                 1000        
2           2020-01-02                 2000   
3           2020-01-02                 3000 
4           2020-01-02                 4000 
5           2020-01-02                 10000 
6           2020-01-02                 6000 
7           2020-01-02                 9000
```

**I want Result**

[image]

in this my query:

```
SELECT
    hospital_payment_data.id,
  chart_num,
    visit,
  chart_name,
  sum(card_amount_received) as card_amount_received,
  credit_card.card_date,
  credit_card.amount as amount,
  if(credit_card.amount = sum(card_amount_received), 'ok', 'error') as result
from hospital_payment_data
left join credit_card on date(credit_card.card_date) = visit AND hospital_payment_data.card_amount_received = credit_card.amount
GROUP BY chart_num, visit
```

in this my wrong result:

[image]

Do I have to add or modify the database table to print as I want? Or do I have to add a relationship? All data values available are specified.

Comment: As you say, you've already asked multiple times. One had an answer you accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135166/how-do-i-output-a-match-after-comparing-two-tables

Comment: @lurker I tried that, but it didn't work out.

Comment: If it didn't work, why did you accept it? You should have commented back on that answer with some information explaining why it did answer your question.

Comment: Part of the problem (and why you haven't gotten responses previously) is that it's totally clear what you're after. I'm looking at your tables and your "I want Result" and having trouble making sense of it. You said, *I want to print the same amount as the wrong amount*, but your desired result table shows "ok" when the amount is the same. You need to explain further what it is you are exactly trying to compare.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which does not exist in MySQL?  It can be simulated; search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. Let me know if you need something else. You should probably have chart_num in credit_card so you can join the tables together.

```
Select hpd.chart_num,
hpd.chart_name
hpd.visit,
hpd.card_amount_received,
cc.card_date, 
CASE WHEN hpd.card_amount_received = SUM(cc.advenced_amount) THEN hpd.card_amount_received  ELSE NULL END AS ‘amount’,
CASE WHEN hpd.card_amount_received > SUM(cc.advenced_amount) THEN ‘error’ ELSE ‘ok’ END AS ‘result’
 from hospital_payment_data hpd
LEFT JOIN credit_card ON cc.chart_num=hpd.chart_num AND 
date(cc.card_date) = date(hpd.visit)
GROUP BY hpd.chart_num, hpd.visit;
```

It would probably be a good idea to have a client_visit table in case a client comes to the office twice in a day or sets up a payment plan where they aren’t paying on the day they come to the office.